# Align text in the putText() in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I have a list of strings like this

```py
['standUp', 'front', 'lookU', 'lookF', 'lookDF', 'HandOnHipR']
```

I want to print it in the following manner on my video:

```py
['standUp', 
'front', 
'lookU', 
'lookF', 
'lookDF', 
'HandOnHipR']
```

I have tried this:

```py
offset = 1
x, y = 5, 400
for idx, list in enumerate(lbls):
    cv2.putText(frame, str(lbls), (x, y+offset*idx), font, 1, (0, 0, 255), 1)
```

The label is a list of lists mentioned at the top. I am confused with the `org` argument in the `putText()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `org` argument is used to choose the position of the text in the image, and the bottom left corner of the text is put at the point `org`.  If you want the text more to the right, you increase the x value, and if you want it lower, you increase the y value.  So each line will be lower because you are increasing the y value with the `offset*idx`.

As you have it, the second argument `str(lbls)` will print out the entire array, that should be changed to the variable for the single element, which you have as `list`.  (However, it's best not to use `list` as a variable because it will replace the built-in function `list()`.  I'll use `lbl` instead.)

Here's an example where the words in the list are printed:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

frame = np.ones([400,400,3])*255
lbls = ['standUp', 'front', 'lookU', 'lookF', 'lookDF', 'HandOnHipR']

offset = 35
x,y = 50,50
for idx,lbl in enumerate(lbls):
    cv2.putText(frame, str(lbl), (x,y+offset*idx), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0,0,0), 2)

plt.imshow(frame)
plt.show()
```

[image]

If you want to have the brackets and punctuation like you show above, you could possibly print them manually.  The first and last elements would need to be printed separately:

```
cv2.putText(frame, '[\''+str(lbls[0])+'\',', (x,y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0,0,0), 2)
for idx,lbl in enumerate(lbls[1:-1]):
    cv2.putText(frame, '\''+str(lbl)+'\',', (x,y+offset*(idx+1)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0,0,0), 2)
cv2.putText(frame, '\''+str(lbls[0])+'\']', (x,y+offset*(idx+2)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0,0,0), 2)
```

[image]

Otherwise, you could change the elements to actually include the punctuation in them.

Answer (score 11):

### Parameters are as follows:

`cv2.putText(img, text, (org), font, fontScale, color, thickness, linetype)`

**img**: your image
**text**: a string of text to print on image
**org**: bottom-left corner of the text string in the image (x,y)
**font**: font type
**fontScale**: font scale
**color**: text color (B,G,R)
**thickness**: text line thickness
**lineType**: line type (8)

### Here is an example that may help.

#### Test image:

[image]

#### Code:

```
import cv2

lbls = ['standUp', 'front', 'lookU', 'lookF', 'lookDF', 'HandOnHipR']

img = cv2.imread("road.jpg")

h,w,c = img.shape

offset = 0

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

for itr, word in enumerate(lbls):
    offset += int(h / len(lbls)) - 10
    cv2.putText(img, word, (20, offset), font, 1, (0, 255, 0), 3)

cv2.imwrite("road_OUT.jpg", img)
```

#### Result:

[image]

Comment: thanks a ton.  the org argument is not well explained in the documentation.